# Can I use %in% to search and match two columns?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe and I have a vector to pull out terms of interest. for a previous project I was using:

`a=data[data$rn %in% y, "Gene"]`

To pull out information into a new vector. Now I have a another job Id like to do.
I have a large dataframe of 15 columns and >100000 rows. I want to search column 3 and 9 for the content in the vector and print this as a new dataframe.

To make this extra annoying the hit could be in v3 and not in v9 and visa versa.

**Working example**

I have striped the dataframe to 3 cols and few rows.

`data <- structure(list(Gene = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("ibp","leuA", "pLeuDn_02", "repA", "repA1"), class = "factor"), LocusTag = structure(c(1L,2L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("pBPS1_01", "pBPS1_02", "pleuBTgp4","pleuBTgp5", "pLeuDn_02"), class = "factor"), hit = structure(c(2L,4L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("2-isopropylmalate synthase", "Ibp protein","ORF1", "repA1 protein", "replication-associated protein"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gene","LocusTag", "hit"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")`

`y <- c("ibp", "orf1")`

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  It may not work because the column names could be different and `rbind` requires the same column names

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Well it give me the coordinates. Ill be back with an example.

Comment: If you want to print a data.frame in return, why not use `data[data$rn %in% y, c("Gene", "hit")]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus it throws back an error saying undefined columns selected.

Comment: In this case we really need an example of your data, there seems to be something going on with your data structure

Comment: Btw, I think you are misinterpreting your code. It doesn't check anything in columns gene and hit. It only returns those columns if the rn column is in y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all R is case sensitive so your example will not collect the third line but I guess you want that extracted. so you would have to change your y to

```
y <- c("ibp", "ORF1")
```

Ok from your example I try to see what you want to achieve I am not sure if this is really what you want but R knows the operator `|` as "or" so you could try something like:

```
new.data<-data[data$Gene %in% y|data$hit %in% y,]
```

if you only want to extract certain columns of your data set you can specify them behind the "," e.g.:

```
new.data<-data[data$Gene %in% y|data$hit %in% y, c("LocusTag","Gene")]
```

Comment: Hi Sarina, This works great. Thanks a mill. Just a quick question. Is there a way to get it to return partial matches? 
Some of the names in my Vector may look like e.g. hokB_2. If hokB was in the table I assume it would not match.

Comment: As far as I know the `%in%` command is not meant to be used for partial matching. I am not familiar with this kind of extraction so I can't help you with that. Is the number of different subcases so long that you can't add them to your y? you can also use `unique(data$Gene)` to access a list with all possible levels you can find in your dataset, maybe that helps